# What documentation was provided with the Amiga 1020 disk drive?

Tags: hardware, amiga, documentation, amiga-1020

The Amiga 1020 was a 5.25" disk drive for use with the Amiga computer.  Anecdotally, I suspect they are somewhat rarer these days because they were a less popular choice for a second drive back in the late 1980's when the 'next big thing' was 3.5" disks.

I am specifically interested in what documentation was provided with the drive when it was new.  I know there was a short 'flip' titled "Connecting the Amiga 5.25 External Disk Drive", and I was able to find a decent scan of the flip on the Internet Archive. (Which I believe is complete with a total of 4 pages devoted to the physical connection of the drive.)  The flip does not mention how to configure the mountlist, how to format disks or how to use any software with the drive; so I am left wondering how a new user would have figured out how to actually use the drive at all.

To add to my confusion, I am uncertain if the Amiga Transformer software was always bundled and provided with a new Amiga 1020 disk drive?  And if so, maybe the documentation for use of the drive was included as part of the Transformer package?

Can anyone enlighten me as to *what really came with the drive* back in the day and how did a new user figure out how to actually use the drive?

Comment: What is a 'flip'? A single page document like a flyer?

Comment: @Edders, Yes, I struggled with what to call it but you have the right idea.  I do not have an original, but it appears to be 4 pages, possibly stapled in the corner (or maybe folded and stapled in the middle).  Page sizes are rectangular but smaller than 8.5 X 11, I would guess maybe 6" x 7".  A flip?... flyer?... insert?   You can find page 1 here, https://archive.org/details/amiga-1020 (download the zip for all 4 pages)

Comment: I can't answer your question about what documentation was included. I suspect at release the A1020 was intended mostly for use with the Transformer software, but I can tell you that Commodore did add the PC Transfer utilities to use the A1020 to transfer files between PC and Amiga via standard MSDOS formatted floppies on the Workbench Extras disk starting with version 1.2 so there was some facility for a new user to use the drive "out of the box" without having extra software or configuration.

Comment: @mnem That's an excellent point and also means that, at time of release in May 1986, the ONLY way to use the A1020 was with Transformer. Using it any other way needed both the "mount" command and the "diskchange" command, which came in the following year with Amiga OS v1.2.

Comment: @BrianH Yeah, I could see no mention of "diskchange" in the original release of the AmigaDOS manual but I wasn't 100% sure how the PC Utilities included from 1.2 on work. They don't mention having to mount the drive first in the documentation so I suspect but can't verify that they bang the hardware directly which is probably how the Transformer software does it as well. I think mount and diskchange are only required to use the drive directly from AmigaDOS.